# CompareTo and If Statement

Tags: java

I am a Java beginner. Now, I try to fix error from my codes. It's said there are 3 error : `else without if`. I kept changing my code but it seems like that I will have more other errors.

I make a program that asks for the last name of the user about how long they have to wait during roll call and I need to use else ifs to make only one statement gets printed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CompareTo
{public static void main( String[] args )
    {   Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        String Name, Carswell, Jones, Smith, Young;
        System.print.out( "What's your last name? ");
        Name = Keyboard.next();   
        "Name".compareTo("Carswell");

        if ( "Name" < "Carswell" )
        {System.out.print( "You dont' have to wait long, " + Name);
        }

        "Name".compareTo("Jones"); 
         else if ( "Name" > "Carswell"  && Name < "Jones" )
        {System.out.print( "that's not bad, "  + Name );
        }

        "Name".compareTo("Smith");
        else if ( "Name" > "Jones" && Name < "Smith")
        {System.out.print( "looks like a bit of a wait, "  + Name );
        }

        "Young".compareTo("Young");
         else if ( "Name" > "Smith" && Name < "Young" )
        {System.out.print( "it's gonna be a while, "  + Name );
        }

        else 
        {System.out.print( "not going anywhere for a while, "  + Name );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting this line to do? "Name".compareTo("Jones"); You are comparing two constant strings and throwing away the result.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
if ( "Name" < "Carswell" )
{System.out.print( "You dont' have to wait long, " + Name);
}

"Name".compareTo("Jones"); //This is the issue
 else if ( "Name" > "Carswell"  && Name < "Jones" )
{System.out.print( "that's not bad, "  + Name );
}
```

You have `"Name".compareTo("Jones");` between if and else if. There should not be any code in between if and else if. Move the above code to either if block or else if block to make your code compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has so many errors but as you said you are getting else if without if then consider this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

class CompareTo{

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String Name, Carswell, Jones, Smith, Young;

    System.out.println( "What's your last name? ");

    Name = keyboard.next();   

    if ( Name.compareTo("Carswell")<0 )
    {
        System.out.print( "You dont' have to wait long, " + Name);
    }

    /*
        if you have an else if after if; then between them
        you cannot write any other code 
        because you cant write an else if without an if 
        thats why you getting error
    */

    else if(Name.compareTo("Carswell") > 0 && Name.compareTo("Jones")<0){
        System.out.print( "that's not bad, "  + Name );
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

//Never use java pre-defined methods as class Names

//variables have to be started with small letters

```
public class TestClass{
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{ 
    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    String Name, Carswell, Jones, Smith, Young;
    System.out.print( "What's your last name? ");
    Name = Keyboard.next();
    if (Name.compareTo("Carswell")<0){
        System.out.print( "You dont' have to wait long, " + Name);
    }
    //You need to use || not &&
    else if (Name.compareTo("Carswell")>0  || Name.compareTo("Jones")<0 ) {
        System.out.print( "that's not bad, "  + Name );
    }
    else if (Name.compareTo("Jones")>0 || Name.compareTo("Smith")<0)
    {
        System.out.print( "looks like a bit of a wait, "  + Name );
    }

    else if ( Name.compareTo("Smith")>0 || Name.compareTo("Young")<0){
        System.out.print( "it's gonna be a while, "  + Name );
    }

    else {
        System.out.print( "not going anywhere for a while, "  + Name );
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package alphabetical_order_example;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class alphabetical_order_example {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // please write your code below. 

     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

     String Name;


       System.out.print("What is your last name? >>> ");
       Name = keyboard.next();


    if (Name.compareTo("Carswell ") < 0 ) {
        System.out.print("You don't have to wait " + Name);
    }
    else if (Name.compareTo("Carswell") > 0  && Name.compareTo("Jones") < 0) {
        System.out.print("That's not Bad " + Name);
    }
    else if (Name.compareTo("Jones") > 0 && Name.compareTo("Smith") < 0) {
        System.out.print("Looks like a bit wait " + Name);

        }
    else if (Name.compareTo("Smith") > 0 && Name.compareTo("Young") < 0 ) {

       }
    else {
        System.out.print("Your not going anywhere for a while " + Name);
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your thoughts with us and explain your code.